# Python: Tweepy.Cursor : 'JSONParser' object has no attribute 'model_factory'

Tags: python, cursor, ipython, tweepy

I am trying to scrape status data from twitter.Facing Error trying to run the below code

```
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,screen_name=screenname).items():
    statuses.append(status)
```

Below is the Error :

> File "", line 3, in 
>       for status in data:
>
> File "C:\Users\Sriram\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py",
>   line 197, in next
>       self.current_page = self.page_iterator.next()
>
> File "C:\Users\Sriram\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py",
>   line 117, in next
>       model = ModelParser().parse(self.method(create=True), data)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sriram\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tweepy\parsers.py", line
>   102, in parse
>       result = model.parse_list(method.api, json)
>
> File "C:\Users\Sriram\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tweepy\models.py",
>   line 65, in parse_list
>       results.append(cls.parse(api, obj))
>
> File "C:\Users\Sriram\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tweepy\models.py",
>   line 81, in parse
>       user_model = getattr(api.parser.model_factory, 'user') if api else User
>
> AttributeError: 'JSONParser' object has no attribute 'model_factory'

Comment: Appears that is an [open bug](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/538)

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same error. I fixed this by removing the JSONParser in the API initialization.

I changed this:

api = tweepy.API(auth, parser=tweepy.parsers.JSONParser())

To this:

api = tweepy.API(auth)